# Insert TornadoFx in Kotlin project

Tags: intellij-idea, kotlin, tornadofx

I'm having some trouble on putting tornadoFx in my project. I'm using the last version of IntellIj, Kotlin and I'm also downloading tornadoFx from here:

[TornadoFxGitLink](https://github.com/edvin/tornadofx)

I added the pom file to Maven and I already tried to change a few things that Readme of tornado recommended to me like use 1.1 kotlin version or updating IDE.

The thing is that when I create a TornadoFx file in the project and I try to build, these error appears:

```
import tornado.fx is apparently an unresolved reference
```

Can someone explain why is this happening or why these errors normally appear?
Thanks in advance, I'm open to all questions due to my bad english.

Comment: If you're using Maven, you shouldn't need to download TornadoFX manually. Just add [the dependency](https://search.maven.org/search?q=g:no.tornado%20AND%20a:tornadofx&core=gav) to your `pom.xml` file. Also, maybe [Using Maven - Kotlin Programming Language](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/using-maven.html) can help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That import is not needed or at all pointing to anything TornadoFX related. The only import you need for the most part is `import tornadofx.*`.

Install the TornadoFX IDEA plugin, and it will add the import for you. You should also start be reading the [guide](https://edvin.gitbooks.io/tornadofx-guide/).

You should not be downloading TornadoFX manually, use Maven or Gradle to import the dependencies.

I recommend trying out TornadoFX in a simple standalone project first, for example by creating a template project using the TornadoFX IDEA Plugin. After you understand the basics you can revisit integrating it into an existing application.